# Using a dropdown menu to show specific pieces of text according to input

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am making a online website with hints for a game i made using HTML and i want the user to be able to use a drop-down-menu to select what level they would like to get a hint of so the other levels won't be spoiled. Online i found some articles talking about

```
<select>
```

and

```
<option>
```

But i could not find any explanation or example of creating the end result i am hoping off. I am (very, very, very) new to html and other coding so if the answers could be explained in a full size html and not using hard terms, that would be greatly appriciated.

If anyone knows how this works and could explain this to me please leave an answer down below.

(Sorry for bad english, I'm Dutch.)

EDIT:
Using JavaScript is not a problem by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is needed to accomplish this. Drop-down menus are not something that can be created with plain html.

Comment: Using JavaScirpt is not a problem as long as someone could explain it to me how to use this javascript.